# runOnUIiThread Not Running In a Thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I was trying to run a small worker thread in the middle of an activity which would get some stuff from a web service and fill a container when it returned.

```
    new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.w("thread", "can read from thread");

            try {                   
                MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Log.w("internal thread", "running");
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // etc
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

The "internal thread: running" would never print in the log, and when I ripped out the contents and just pasted it into the main body of the method, it worked. My conclusion is that the doubly nested thread never ran. Why would that happen? Am I misusing runOnUiThread?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to output the exception? `Log.e("Test", "exception", e);` in the block where u catch it.

Comment: Yea, it doesn't go into that block either. It's bizarre. It seems to skip over the entire thing.

Comment: Truth be told I'm not sure I want to use threads anymore, but I am extremely interested in understanding why this didn't work at all. +1 for the helpful suggestion though :-)

Comment: @SapphireSun, did the previous Log entry run?

Comment: @st0le "thread: can read from thread" did indeed print

Comment: @SapphireSun, I can't reproduce this. It works fine here. Where have you placed this code snippet? is it in some other class? while running this, is your `MyActivity` in focus?

Comment: It's located inside of the current activity (a PreferenceActivity) and inside a method call made from an OnPreferenceChangeListener.

Answer (score 0):

> Why would that happen? Am I misusing runOnUiThread?

Yeas ! runOnUiThread is other thread than Main thread. i suggest to have a look at Android Handler.